# como puedo instalar pythoncom?

Tags: python

[image: como podria instalar pythoncom?]

vi en otros post que tengo que instalar pywin32 y lo hice pero aun asi no funciona nada. Lo necesito porque estoy haciendo un programa de Texto a voz con pyttsx3 y a la hora de correr el programa me pide el pythoncom

Comment: Tenés varias versiones de Python instaladas? Si es así, estás seguro de que estás instalando las librerías en la misma versión que en la que ejecutas el script?

Comment: sii tenia 2 versiones ahora acabe de desinstalar el antiguo, muchas gracias amigo por la ayuda ahora si ya funciona.

Comment: Aquí en la comunidad no se coloca solucionado al título de la pregunta, si encontraste la solución entonces y si quieres puedes responderla en el espacio dedicado a ello (debajo de la publicación donde dice: **Tu respuesta**)

Comment: @BetaM Oscarjsjsjs Sería en la zona de respuestas, no la de comentarios. Aclaro eso para evitar que el OP publique su solución en forma de comentario y ambas secciones estan debajo de la publicación.

Comment: @BetaM estoy al tanto de a que te referías, pero hice la aclaración más para el OP que para vos.

Comment: Por cierto, de nada Oscar!